# print instance of object in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am a beginning python learner. Why is this code not printing 100?

```
class Pet(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.name = ''
        self.age = 0

    def getName(self, newname):
        self.name = newname
        return self.name

    def getAge(self, aging):
        self.age += aging
        return self.age


polly = Pet()
polly.getAge(100)
print polly.getAge
```

Comment: Because you're not actually calling the function.

Comment: A function named `getAge` probably should not be modifying anything.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response but my intention was polly supposed to be outside of the class, can you please post a fix to where it should print 100 to the screen?

Comment: Stop downvoting this people... we were all beginners once and we all made mistakes like this (I certainly did, and so did most people I know). This is actually a decent beginner question since OP posted a concise working code snippet. Be welcoming to the new kid!

Comment: The world is beautiful place because of people like you... Thank you!!

Answer (score 5):

1) You meant `print polly.getAge()` instead of `print polly.getAge`.

2) However you then have a second issue (`getAge()` requires `aging` to be mandatory, which it totally shouldn't). You can kludge that with `print polly.getAge(0)`, or fix it properly, see below.

Back to 1) The former actually calls the function/method (well it tries to call it, except for the issue of 2)) 
The latter is wrong, it only prints information about the actual function/method, but doesn't actually call it.

You can explore more by seeing that `type(polly.getAge())` (or `type(polly.getAge(0))`) is an int, different to `type(polly.getAge)`, which will be some type for function/method.

2) **Your second issue here is `getAge(...)` is pretending to be a getter function but it also has a mandatory parameter `aging` and is implementing the aging, this is considered "method abuse"** and violates separation of concerns, or at least don't name it `getX` which is really reserved for getters. Your alternatives are a) give it a default `getAge(self, aging=0)` (or use @property decorator), now it behaves like a getter when called `getAge()`. Or b) refactor out the two separate pieces of functionality into separate methods ("separation of concerns"):

```
class Pet(object):
    ...
    def getAge(self, aging):
        return self.age

    def doAging(self, aging):
        self.age += aging
        # Note that doAging() has no return value, and that is correct behavior (it's a method, not a getter)
```

In general that is a better and more maintainable design, we frown on "magical getters/setters" with side-effects, for tons of reasons (one of which is they f### up unit-testing). As you start adding more methods, you'll see why very quickly...

Comment: Which would itself fail because `getAge` takes a required argument.

Comment: @ppperry: right, I didn't see that `aging` was a mandatory parameter, I assumed OP would give it a default `getAge(self, aging=0)`. This is "method abuse", since getAge is no longer a getter, it should be `age(...)` or `doAging(...)`

Comment: I don't appreciate the tactical downvoters... I wrote a valid answer and I didn't notice at first that aging was a mandatory parameter, since noone ever writes a getter with a mandatory parameter that changes the object.

Comment: @Kamaal if you got it to work, please mark an answer

Answer (score 5):

Step through it.

```
polly = Pet()  # initialize a new Pet
polly.getAge(100)  # add 100 to polly.age
print polly.getAge   # print the getAge method bound to polly
```

Did you maybe mean to do

```
polly = Pet()
polly.getAge(100)
print polly.age
```

Or:

```
polly = Pet()
print polly.getAge(100)
```

?

No matter what, you should be nice and not mutate values with a `getX` method. It's definitely unexpected behavior.

Comment: polly = Pet()
print polly.getAge(100) #thank you this works

Answer (score 3):

Really you should have a method for setting and getting the age.

```
class Pet(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.name = ''
        self.age = 0

    def getName(self, newname):
        self.name = newname
        return self.name

    def getAge(self):
        return self.age

    def setAge(self, newage):
        self.age = newage
        return None

polly = Pet()
polly.setAge(100)
print (polly.getAge())
```

Comment: I'd prefer to see setters returning `None` to match the style in the stdlib (mutators like `list.sort`, etc), but YMMV

Comment: Point taken, I have included your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Here is the modified code. I hope this will help you.

```
class Pet:

##    def __init__(self):
##        self.name = ''
##        self.age = 0

    def setAge(self, age):
        self.age = age
        #return self.age

    def getAge(self):
##        self.age = aging
##        return self.age
        print self.age


polly = Pet()
polly.setAge(100)
polly.getAge()
#print (polly.getAge)
```